# Issue Reading CANVAS DOM Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I'm trying to access the `backgroundImage.src` value in the following canvas element object - to no avail.

I can access the backgroundColor PERFECTLY. i.e. `object.backgroundColor`. but can't get the **backgroundImage src**.

I've tried `object.backgroundImage.src`, `object['backgroundImage']['src']`, and even `object['backgroundImage.src']`.

No dice. Where am I going wrong here?

[image]

**JSON pulled from database, that creates the canvas object:**

```
{"objects":[{"type":"i-text","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":71.61,"top":237.86,"width":395.77,"height":63.28,"fill":"#FFF","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"Oh. You need a little dummy text\nfor your mockup? How quaint.","fontSize":28,"fontWeight":"300","fontFamily":"Roboto, sans-serif","fontStyle":"","lineHeight":1,"textDecoration":"","textAlign":"center","textBackgroundColor":"","charSpacing":0,"styles":{}}],"background":"#CCC","backgroundImage":{"type":"image","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":270,"top":270,"width":812.54,"height":540,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"crossOrigin":"anonymous","alignX":"none","alignY":"none","meetOrSlice":"meet","src":"https://pixabay.com/get/e837b90f2df7063ed95c4518b74d4495e073e3d504b0154994f7c679a0eeb4_960.jpg","filters":[{"type":"Tint","color":"#59ABE3","opacity":0.5}],"resizeFilters":[]}}
```

Comment: I don't see any JSON code anywhere. What is that image of?

Comment: There's an `i` property at the top, so it should be `object.i.backgroundImage.src`

Comment: This looks more like a DOM element than JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. It's a `canvas` object, not JSON. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = JSON.parse('{\"objects\":[{\"type\":\"i-text\",\"originX\":\"left\",\"originY\":\"top\",\"left\":71.61,\"top\":237.86,\"width\":395.77,\"height\":63.28,\"fill\":\"#FFF\",\"stroke\":null,\"strokeWidth\":1,\"strokeDashArray\":null,\"strokeLineCap\":\"butt\",\"strokeLineJoin\":\"miter\",\"strokeMiterLimit\":10,\"scaleX\":1,\"scaleY\":1,\"angle\":0,\"flipX\":false,\"flipY\":false,\"opacity\":1,\"shadow\":null,\"visible\":true,\"clipTo\":null,\"backgroundColor\":\"\",\"fillRule\":\"nonzero\",\"globalCompositeOperation\":\"source-over\",\"transformMatrix\":null,\"skewX\":0,\"skewY\":0,\"text\":\"Oh. You need a little dummy text\\nfor your mockup? How quaint.\",\"fontSize\":28,\"fontWeight\":\"300\",\"fontFamily\":\"Roboto, sans-serif\",\"fontStyle\":\"\",\"lineHeight\":1,\"textDecoration\":\"\",\"textAlign\":\"center\",\"textBackgroundColor\":\"\",\"charSpacing\":0,\"styles\":{}}],\"background\":\"#CCC\",\"backgroundImage\":{\"type\":\"image\",\"originX\":\"center\",\"originY\":\"center\",\"left\":270,\"top\":270,\"width\":812.54,\"height\":540,\"fill\":\"rgb(0,0,0)\",\"stroke\":null,\"strokeWidth\":0,\"strokeDashArray\":null,\"strokeLineCap\":\"butt\",\"strokeLineJoin\":\"miter\",\"strokeMiterLimit\":10,\"scaleX\":1,\"scaleY\":1,\"angle\":0,\"flipX\":false,\"flipY\":false,\"opacity\":1,\"shadow\":null,\"visible\":true,\"clipTo\":null,\"backgroundColor\":\"\",\"fillRule\":\"nonzero\",\"globalCompositeOperation\":\"source-over\",\"transformMatrix\":null,\"skewX\":0,\"skewY\":0,\"crossOrigin\":\"anonymous\",\"alignX\":\"none\",\"alignY\":\"none\",\"meetOrSlice\":\"meet\",\"src\":\"https:\/\/pixabay.com\/get\/e837b90f2df7063ed95c4518b74d4495e073e3d504b0154994f7c679a0eeb4_960.jpg\",\"filters\":[{\"type\":\"Tint\",\"color\":\"#59ABE3\",\"opacity\":0.5}],\"resizeFilters\":[]}}');

console.log(x.backgroundImage.src);
```

Prints out `https://pixabay.com/get/e837b90f2df7063ed95c4518b74d4495e073e3d504b0154994f7c679a0eeb4_960.jpg`

Comment: Thanks, but get this error: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'object.backgroundImage.i')`

Comment: how are you getting that canvas object in the first place?

Comment: I'm also a little confused why you get the backgroundColor, when you capitalize the b.

Comment: Database...stored JSON.

Comment: Typo on the capitalized B. Fixed. Should be lowercase.

Comment: What `B`? What are you talking about?

Comment: @lonut non-issue now. Was a typo in question. I've fixed. ;)

Comment: @manonthemat I find it weird I can access `object.backgroundColor` string which returns the value. But can't get nested object for `backgroundImage`?

Comment: can you just post the json from the database then?

Comment: @lonut no lol Typo dude. manonthemat was confused how I was able to access the value. !!?

Comment: What did you actually saved in the database?

Comment: @manonthemat Added JSON. Not clean. Just dumped from database.

Comment: Parsing the JSON and assigning it to a variable x, I can get `x.backgroundImage.src`

Comment: Yes, I can get this as well now, thanks! Issue is I'm now parsing the JSON in two separate spots. When I'm loading the canvas from JSON (Fabric.js does this automatically in their `loadFromJSON()` method), so I was hoping to just read the canvas object directly. Versus a new var and parsing the same data over again.

Comment: That's why you should always provide code in your questions.

Comment: Yeah, I know I made the question overly complicated to begin with. We've gone to far for me to re-write question lol

Comment: It also depends on how you save the data in the database (and what kind of database it is), when you retrieve the data. If the data is just saved as a stringified(!) object, then you still have to parse it (either manually or implicitly) when retrieving the data anyway.

Comment: It's stringified. Fabric.js parses data when it loads/creates data from JSON.

Comment: `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(); canvas.loadFromJSON(yourJson);` ?

Comment: Exactly! So I guess my real question is how to get the backgroundImage value from the canvas object.

Comment: Just going to accept this. Found an alternative method to do what I'm looking to do - but this is my fallback. i.e. to parse the JSON again and get value from that. Thanks for your help!